# Cocomplete base category implies cocomplete slice category

Tags: category-theory

I'm having trouble with the final step of the proof that if $\mathsf C$ is a cocomplete category, so is each of its slice categories.

Here's the proof given in Borceux's *Handbook of Categorical Algebra*:

[image]

I understand everything except the very last sentence. Why is the conclusion immediate?

Comment: Try to prove the universal property for the alleged colimit of $F$ in $\mathscr{C}/I$.

Comment: There is a typo, it should be $\gamma_D : G(D) \to I$.

Comment: It is *not immediate* that $((L,\lambda),(s_D))$ is a colimit of $F$. It is *easy to see*, but one really has to check this. Details can be found for example in Mac Lane's book. But this is also a good exercise which one can easily solve.

Answer (score 2):

By construction $\left( (L,\lambda),(s_D)_{D \in \mathscr{D}} \right)$ is a cocone on $F$.
If $\left( (M,m),(q_D)_{D \in \mathscr{D}} \right)$ is another cocone on $F$, 
then $\left( M,(q_D)_{D \in \mathscr{D}} \right)$ is a cocone on $G$. By the universal property of colimits there is a unique factorization $l : L \to M$, 
such that $l \circ s_D = q_D$ for all $D \in \mathscr{D}$. It is now left to prove that 
$\lambda = m \circ l$. 
We have 
$$
  m \circ l \circ s_D = m \circ q_D = \gamma_D = \lambda \circ s_D.
$$
The result now follows from the uniqueness of factorization $L \to I$ (It is the dualized version of proposition 2.6.4 in Borceux's book). This reasoning is fairly easy and could be found in earlier proofs.

*Typo:* As it was mentioned in the comments, morphisms $\gamma_D$ must map $GD \to I$.